# Filter results in ManyToMany relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```py
class Role(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, through=UserRole, through_fields={"user", "role"})


class UserRole(models.Model):
  role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  comments = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I also have an API that allows query by roles. The API can specify multiple roles and we select only users that have ALL those roles.

```py
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = UserSerializerClass
  
  def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    queries = self.request.query_params.getlist('q')
    filter_query = Q()
    for query in queries:
      filter_query &= Q(roles__id__in=[query])
    return queryset.exclude(~filter_query).distinct()
```

And finally my serializer classes are:

```py
class UserRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  role = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='role.name')

  class Meta:
    model = UserRole
    fields = ['role', 'comments']


class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Role
    fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  roles = UserRoleSerializer(source='userrole_set', many=True)

  class User:
    model = User
    fields = ['name', 'roles']
```

While querying this API with given roles, e.g., `/api/users?q=1&q=2` where we're trying to fetch users with roles with id 1 and 2, I get the users but the users contain all the roles they have. Is there a way to narrow down the list of roles to only the ones queried, so that we can show the comments for those roles in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out only the specific roles you require using `Preftech` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queries = self.request.query_params.getlist('q')
        prefetch_roles = Prefetch('userrole_set', queryset=Role.objects.filter(id__in=queries))
        queryset = User.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch_roles)
        ...
```

Comment: For some reason this breaks pagination. The first page loads fine (though it returns all users, even if they don't have any role in the query, but has empty roles list), but next page gives me an error `'role' object has no attribute 'user_id'`

Comment: My answer is only about prefetch roles you need for user. User filtering and pagination issues need to be dealt with separately. To filter users, you can use `Subquery()`, to solve the problem with pagination, additional context needed.